# Exception occured while replacing "[" String in java

Tags: java, android

**I want to remove "[" and "]" character from string.**

**My Code is:**

```
String original=data.replaceAll("]|[", "");
```

**I am getting error:**

```
09-19 13:25:55.755: E/AndroidRuntime(25007): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-19 13:25:55.755: E/AndroidRuntime(25007): java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Syntax error U_REGEX_MISSING_CLOSE_BRACKET near index 3:
09-19 13:25:55.755: E/AndroidRuntime(25007): ]|[
09-19 13:25:55.755: E/AndroidRuntime(25007):    ^
09-19 13:25:55.755: E/AndroidRuntime(25007):    at com.ibm.icu4jni.regex.NativeRegEx.open(Native Method)
09-19 13:25:55.755: E/AndroidRuntime(25007):    at java.util.regex.Pattern.compileImpl(Pattern.java:383)
09-19 13:25:55.755: E/AndroidRuntime(25007):    at java.util.regex.Pattern.<init>(Pattern.java:341)
09-19 13:25:55.755: E/AndroidRuntime(25007):    at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Pattern.java:358)
09-19 13:25:55.755: E/AndroidRuntime(25007):    at java.lang.String.replaceAll(String.java:2004)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use instead

```
String original=data.replaceAll("\\]|\\[", "");
```

Comment: My Java is rusty, but shouldn't those backslashes be doubled, to present actual backslashes to the reg ex parser?

Comment: yep, fixed, double slashes

Comment: Or using a character class `[\\[\\]]`…